# How to encourage positive developer behavior with an IDE?

Tags: ide

The goal of IDEs is increase productivity. They do a great job at that. Refactoring, navigation, inline documentation, auto completion help increase productivity immensely.

But: **Every tool is a weapon**. The very same IDE helps to produce chunk code. Some IDE features are an invitation to produce bad code: code generation, code formatting tools, refactoring tools.

IDE overuse tends to isolate developers from the necessary details. It is **a good thing that you can start working** but at some point in your career you have to be able to figure out how to start a process. You can ignore this detail for some time, in the end they are important to write a working product (vs. bolted together stuff that works 90% of the time).

**How do you encourage positive behavior of other developers working with an IDE?** This is a question as old as copy and paste.

To get the right impression: **developers have to have the maximum freedom to mobilize their maximum creativity and motivation**. They may use IDEs and all the related tools as they see fit. Nobody should impose draconian measures on them. I don't want to demotivate and force someone to do something. Good behavior has to be encouraged. It has to itch little a bit if you do the wrong thing. In the same line as the SO "accept rate" metric (and reputation). You can ignore it but **life is better if you follow the rules**.

(The solution should work in a given setting. You can ignore reviews, changing the staffing or more education as potential solutions.)

Answer (score 3):

**Train your IDE, instead of being trained by it.**

Set up code formatting the way you (or your team) wants it. Heck, even disable it in cases where it makes sense. I've never seen an IDE align something like this with a sensible combination of tabs and spaces (where `\t` is obviously the tab character):

```
{
\tcout << "Hello "
\t     << (some + long + expression +
\t         to_produce_the_word(world))
\t     << endl;
}
```

In languages like Java, you cannot avoid boilerplate. The best option you have is to check generated code, ensuring that it is the same as what you'd have written by hand. Modify it as necessary. Configure your IDE to generate the exact code that you need, if possible. Eclipse is pretty good at this.

Answer (score 1):

**Know what's going on under the hood.**

Know that your IDE is actually invoking the compiler. Have some insight into the flags that it passes. Be able to invoke the compiler from the command line.

Know about the runtime system. Be aware of the flags that are used or needed to launch your program. Be able to launch the program from a command line.

Answer (score 1):

I think before anyone uses  a RAD tool of any type they should be able to write the application from scratch (scratch being wiring together the framework components) in notepad potentially on a computer that is 10 years older than current technology :P. Not knowing the ins and outs of a paradigm/framework leads to bad code from novice developers who only learn things at a mile high view of the platforms they develop for. Perhaps they should do this in a few technologies -- i.e., GTK programming is completely different to MVC which is then also different to SWING and .NET.

I think the end result should be a developer that thinks of the finer details of a problem before they jump to thinking of how they will write an interface to it in a specific RAD environment.

Answer (score 0):

its an open ended question, but...

We have a Eclipse format file that everyone shares, so that we all format the code in the same manor. (Except the one lone InteliJ guy we have).

Everyone shares a dictionary file. It helps to remove all the red lines from the code. Making it look cleaner and more readable.

I run EMMA over the code to find out who isn't testing their code, and then moan at them.

The main problems we face is that most of the team don't know all the features/power of the IDE (eclipse). The didn't know about CTRL + O (twice), or auto code gen. All I can do as a 'hot key wizard' is keep sharing my knowledge with them to help them become more productive.

I look forward to the day when my problem is that they auto gen as much as possible.
Rather than me finding bugs where the wrong value is returned from a getter method due to a typo.

Answer (score 0):

Attempt development (at least occasionally) using only a text editor and launching the compilation, testing, etc. from the command line.

Typing the commands will get tedious very quickly so create scripts or (even better) learn rake, ant, msbuild.

If the IDE does code generation for you and that code generation is really important (such as generating classes from xsd or proxy classes from wsdl), try to find out how to run the code generation from the command line - then hook the code generation into a build (so you'll never be tempted to edit the generated code).

The idea of autoformatting code is great but it usually just turns your code into a mess.  If you have less code, minor formatting inconsistencies are just not a big deal.

Adding code quality tools into your build - style checks, class and method sizes, complexity, code duplication, test coverage, etc (complexian, simian, flog, flay, ndepend, ncover, etc.) will discourage IDE generated code.